# Multiple JsonObject in one .put

Tags: java, json, microservices

I'm having problem adding a json to the java code,
I have these parameters

The compiler shows error, could you help me

```
.put("person",new JsonObject().put("name",("Luis"), new JsonObject().put("phoneNumber",("526677777777"))))
```

JSON :

```
"person": {
"name": "Luis",
"phoneNumber": "526677777777"
}
```

The error reports is_:

> Error:(147, 47) java: no suitable method found for put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject)

Comment: Try pasting the full code block where it is throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to add too much of values ot the json and there's no method with three params in a signature. I think there's an error in your code.

```
put("name",("Luis"), new JsonObject().put("phoneNumber",("526677777777")))
```

there's defenetelly an error with that `("Luis")`

Maybe it should be something like that:

```
    JsonObject person = new JsonObject();
    person.put(new  JsonObject("name", "Luis"));
    person.put(new  JsonObject("phoneNumber", "526677777777"));
```

Comment: Its Work  thanks
                .put("person", new JsonObject().put("name","Luis").put("phoneNumber","526677777777"))

Comment: @user12047512 That is the solution I wrote, not Michel_T...His solution is creating 3 `JSONObject` which is also not the correct solution, when you only show two.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example `JSON`, there should only be 2 JSON Objects not three with the inner `JSON` object containing `name` and `phoneNumber`.

It also helps to format things on separate lines, try this:

```
yourInitialObject.put("person",new JsonObject()
                              .put("name","Luis")
                              .put("phoneNumber","526677777777"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should give your expected JSON structure,

```
//create a json object to hold the json elements
JsonObject jsonElements = new JsonObject();
jsonElements.put("name","Luis");
jsonElements.put("phoneNumber","526677777777");
//now create another json object to hold the json element created
JsonObject jsonMain = new JsonObject();
jsonMain.put("person",jsonElements);
```